# How to understand two pairs of parentheses in this code fragment?

Tags: c++, hash

This code is from *C++ primer* p.446:

```
return hash<string>() (sd.isbn());
```

I don't understand the return expression with two pairs of parentheses. There's no similar syntax in front of the book.

Comment: Hard to tell without context

Comment: Depends on what `hash<string>()` returns. If it's returning a class with an overridden call operator, there's nothing special with that.

Comment: In C++11 and onward, you can use `std::hash<std::string>{}` (ie, braces instead of parentheses) to build an object. It makes differentiating between object construction and function calls easier.

Comment: It's amusing how Cpp is full of those hard to understand tidbits. I deeply respect those who work primarily on this language - you need a huge deal of skill and memory to be a good C++ developer!

Comment: @ThalesPereira a huge deal of skill and memory is also useful to be a good C++ compiler

Comment: @ThalesPereira Most modern languages have things like this. For instance, Javascript IIFE. Although I admit that C++ templates add an extra opportunity for complex syntax. But if you just learn to break expressions down into their components, and understand each of them, things become pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is a class type.  What you are doing here is constructing a temporary `std::hash` with `hash<string>()` and then `(sd.isbn())` calls the [`operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator()) of that temporary passing it `sd.isbn()`.

It would be the same as

```
std::hash<std::string> temp;
return temp(sd.isbn());
```

For more reading on using objects that have a `operator()` see: [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: To add to this good answer. The `temp(sd.isbn())` might seem confusing here because it's an object. The object is basically used as a function object, a [functor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).

Comment: @GillBates Good call.  Added a link in the answer.

Comment: I'd consider this another good argument for curly-bracket initialization to clarify that you're constructing an object, e.g.: `return hash<string>{} (sd.isbn());`