# Why is {} used to access operator() in std::hash?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map, std

While reading the examples of std::hash used for std::unordered_map, I noticed that the operator() function was being accessed by {}.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

```
result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
{
    result_type const h1 ( std::hash<std::string>{}(s.first_name) );
    result_type const h2 ( std::hash<std::string>{}(s.last_name) );
    return h1 ^ (h2 << 1); // or use boost::hash_combine (see Discussion)
}
```

What does the use of {} here represent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Comment: I wish C++ allowed `static operator()`s.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024008/how-to-understand-two-pairs-of-parentheses-in-this-code-fragment

Comment: @DanielH why? C++ allows static functions, and the name of the function doesnt really matter, does it? It is rather the advantage (or the use case) of functors that you want to have a state attached to the function you call

Comment: @DanielH Which would basically be ... constructors which return a type of your choosing.  Madness.

Comment: @tobi303 For an example of where this would be useful, look at the question I commented on. `std::hash` would be easier to use if it were called as `std::hash<std::string>(s)` instead of having the extra `{}`. You can’t do partial function specialization, or lambda specialization or overloading at all, but you can do partial type specialization.

Comment: @Yakk There are a number of differences between constructors and functions other than their names.

Comment: it is a somewhat duplicate question, sorry. I didn't think to search using the words curly bracket.  The answer is obvious now, and I added a comment to the answer below specifically calling out documentation for lines of code like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::hash<T>` is a type not a function.

An instance of `std::hash` has an `operator()` that does the hash.

So `std::hash<std::string>` is a hashing type.  `{}` then creates an instance of that type.  `(s.first_name)` calls `operator()` on a `std::hash<std::string>`.

```
std::hash<std::string>{}(s.first_name);
^                     ^       ^
|                     |   call operator() on that instance
type of hasher        |
                create an instance of that type
```

Comment: @erip will you give me an upvote if I do the same? Just kidding :P I was actually going to draw something similar but I was too slow

Comment: @tobi303 I'll upvote if you add freehand red circles.

Comment: you are quite demanding, but I am also quite not motivated to do anything else :P

Comment: So it is just aggregate initialization of the object.

I had never written it in a line like that so it threw me off.

2nd form in Syntax list for c++11
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: class template, not type :-P

Comment: @barry the section ends at the `>` not the `<`.

Comment: @Yakk Talking about your first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

`std::hash` is not a function, but a class, more specifically a functor. So you have to create an object of that class before you can call its `operator()`.

[image]

Comment: is it really a freehand? :>

Comment: Looks freehand.  Sadly I didn't say "only if", so I had already upvoted.  ;)  But +1 freehand red circles.