# What does static_cast mean when it's followed by two pairs of parentheses?

Tags: c++, function-object

What does [this](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/blob/2c4687431f978f02a3780e24b8b701d22aa32d9c/bytell_hash_map.hpp#L1004) say:

```
return static_cast<Hasher &>(*this)(key);
```

?

I can't tell whether `*this` or `key` is passed to `static_cast`. I looked around and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024058/4397162), but unlike what I'm stuck on, there's nothing inside the first pair of parentheses.

Comment: I think the piece of the puzzle you're missing is that `Hasher` has an overloaded "function call operator", and can be used as a function.

Comment: You're right that the question you linked has a significant difference: it's creating a temporary object of a class type, not using `static_cast` on an existing object.  (The answer there explains why that uses empty (), and the fact that this is `static_cast<>()` explains why the first parens are non-empty.)  But in both cases, `operator( something )` of the resulting object is being invoked.

Comment: If you are unsure about the order of evaluation, just add extra parentheses to disambiguate.

Comment: @HenriMenke if they don't know the order of evaluation, how are they supposed to know where to put the parentheses?

Comment: @ChrisH You don't. But you might get lucky when the compiler only accepts one alternative.

Answer (score 34):

The statement is parsed as

```
return (static_cast<Hasher &>(*this))(key);
```

So, the argument to `static_cast` is `*this`. Then the result of the cast, let's call it `x`, is used as postfix-expression in a function call with `key` as argument, i.e. `x(key)`, the result of which is returned.

Answer (score 8):

> I can't tell whether `*this` or `key` is passed to `static_cast`

If you're unsure, you can just look up the syntax.

In the informal documentation, the only available syntax for [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) is:

```
static_cast < new-type > ( expression )
```

and the same is true in any [standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#:static_cast) you compare.

So there is no `static_cast<T>(X)(Y)` syntax, and the only possible interpretation is:

- `new-type = Hasher&`
- `expression = *this`

and the overall statement is equivalent to

```
Hasher& __tmp = static_cast<Hasher &>(*this);
return __tmp(key);
```

In the [skarupke/flat_hash_map](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/) code you linked, the interpretation is that this class has a function call operator inherited from the private base class `Hasher`, and it wants to call that *explicitly* - ie, `Hasher::operator()` rather than any other inherited `operator()`. You'll note the same mechanism is used to explicitly call the other privately-inherited function call operators.

It would be more legible if it used a different function name for each of these policy type parameters, but then you couldn't use `std::equal_to` directly for the `Equal` parameter, for example.

It might also be more legible if it used data members rather than private inheritance for `Hasher`, `Equal` etc. but this way is chosen to allow the [empty base-class optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) for stateless policies.

Comment: *"The interpretation is that the class has a function call operator inherited from the private base class Hasher"* : **not necessarily**. The class is just **explicitly convertible to `Hasher&`**. It may be due to inheritance or a costume **convertion operator** or both( inheritance from a class with conversion operator).

Comment: I followed the link to the [skarupke/flat_hash_map](https://github.com/skarupke/flat_hash_map/) in the question and am explaining how to understand that code. I know there are other possible interpretations of the quoted line in general. Have clarified the distinction.

Comment: I mean, you should've mention the broader case of **explicit convertiblity** rather than special case of inheritance which may or may not be the actual case. Otherwise your answer is very descrptive as a whole.

Comment: I mean, that doesn't affect how the cast is parsed, which was the original question. I only described the interpretation to give OP some context for understanding this code they're reading, I don't want to write an essay on all the different ways the cast itself can be performed.

Comment: Interpreting tha cast as inheritance is simply wrong.

Comment: This _specific_ code is explicitly up-casting `this` to a private base class, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I don't see anything in the context pointing toward inheritance. I'd be happy, if you could show me where in the context of the question you found   an upcast. If it were an upcast, casting by pointer would exactly do the job(`(*static_cast<Hasher*>(this))();`). The fact that a reference cast is used points toward the more generic case of explicit convertiblity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244691/discussion-between-useless-and-red-wave).